# avoid unnecessary matrix multiplications with sparse dummies

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
catVar = np.array(list('abcbca')) #categorical independent variable
groupIDs = np.array([10,10,20,20,30,30]) #groups(/strata)
p = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 1, 0]) #'probabilities'
dummies = pd.get_dummies(catVar)

_,idx,tags = np.unique(groupIDs, return_index=1, return_inverse=1)
np.add.reduceat((p * dummies.T).T, idx)[tags]
[[ 0.5   0.5   0.  ]
 [ 0.5   0.5   0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.75  0.25]
 [ 0.    0.75  0.25]
 [ 0.    0.    1.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    1.  ]]
```

In the last two lines of code, I am creating a new table with the sum of products between p and X per group for each column. Because my data set is ~ .5m x 4k, this calculation takes quite some time which I am trying to reduce. My question is, whether it would be possible to get the same result when I define my dummies as a sparse matrix,

```
from scipy import sparse
dumSp = sparse.csc_matrix(dummies)
```

and whether the output of the above calculation could go directly to a sparse matrix as well.

Comment: Why not try it and see what happens?

Comment: the problem is that the way I am storing the indices of the groups now has no way of knowing where there are zeros on each specific column on the dummy matrix so I know for fact that it is not going to work. I cannot figure a way to dynamically shorten the group indices depending on where ones are on each column of the dummies

Comment: `dumSp.T.multiply(p)` can substitute for `p *dummies.T`, but the result is still dense (`np.matrix`).

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about `multiply`